# Who came up with the phrase thunder rolling and how

Tags: etymology

People say *thunder rolls* but why is it that and who came up with the phrase. I came to the thought as i was sitting through a thunderstorm a while back and wanted to know the truth behind it.

Comment: The term comes from the sound of thunder in some cases -- similar to the sound of a bowling ball rolling, or a cask rolling down a plank, or something of that nature.

Answer (score 3):

The OED attests to *roll* in the sense of reverberating thunder from 1602,

> Such a dreadfull roaring, as if it had beene a long rowle of thunder.

in Anthony Munday's translation of *The Third Part of the History of Palmerin of England*, and even earlier as a verb meaning to reverberate or re-echo, attested from around 1522 in Gavin Douglas's translation of Virgil's *Æneid*:

> Endlang the costis the vocis and the sowndis Rollys inclusyt, quhill the mekyll hyllys Bemys agane.

The etymological note suggests it comes via Norman French *rouler*, meaning to turn over repeatedly, but with a long chain of derived meanings as to move something by turning it over repeatedly, to fashion into a ball or cylinder, and to move on wheels, and finally to make a prlonged sound, perhaps suggestive of turning wheels or rolling balls.

Comment: The etymological note suggesting the 'make a sound' definition of _rouler_ is very convincing.

Answer (score 1):

Writers—and especially poets—have linked the noun *thunder* with the verb *roll* for a long time. A Google Books search finds multiple poems written before 1725 that make this connection.

One early instance appears in Charles Montague, Lord Halifax's "[On the Death of King Charles II](https://books.google.com/books?id=X0kJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA382&dq=%22fright+the+Bad+thus+awful+Thunder+rolls%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbgqqV1bXPAhUB62MKHeEOAGE4ChDoAQhBMAc#v=onepage&q=%22fright%20the%20Bad%20thus%20awful%20Thunder%20rolls%22&f=false)" (1685), included in *A Collection of Poems* (1702):

> To fright the Bad thus awful ***Thunder* rolls**;/ While the bright *Bow* secures the Faithful Souls,/ Such is thy Glory, *Charles*, thy lasting name,/ Brighter than our proud *Neighbour*'s guilty Fame:

Another is from Thomas Parnell, [*An Essay on the Different Stiles of Poetry*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JPRbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA11&dq=%22thunder+rolls%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOqJbd0bXPAhVQ6GMKHTJQDRcQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22thunder%20rolls%22&f=false) (1713):

> Mount higher still, still keep thy faithful Seat,/ Mind the firm Reins, and curb thy *Courser*'s Heat;/ Nor let him touch the *Realms* that next appear,/ Whose hanging Turrets seem a Fall to fear,/ And strangely stand along the Tracts of Air/ Where **Thunder rolls**, and bearded Comets glare.

Parnell uses a similar wording in "[The Hermit](https://books.google.com/books?id=W0wJAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22o%27er+their+heads+loud-rolling+thunder+ran%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic5Z-x2LXPAhVO3GMKHRBYB50Q6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22o%27er%20their%20heads%20loud-rolling%20thunder%20ran%22&f=false)" (by 1718) in *Poems on Several Occasions* (1722):

> As near the *Miser*'s heavy doors they drew,/ Fierce rising Gusts with sudden Fury blew;/ The nimble Light'ning mix'd with Show'rs began,/ And o'er their Heads **loud-rolling Thunder** ran.

Alexander Pope's translation/reworking of [*The Iliad of Homer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6V1eAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA184&dq=%22thunder+rolls%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOqJbd0bXPAhVQ6GMKHTJQDRcQ6AEIRTAH#v=onepage&q=%22thunder%20rolls%22&f=false), volume 2 (1720) uses the phrase "thunder rolls" twice:

> For what remains; let fun'ral flames be fed/ With heroes corps: I war not with the dead:/ Go search your slaughter'd chiefs on yonder plain,/ And gratify the *Manes* of the slain./ Be witness, *Jove*, whose **thunder rolls** on high!/ He said and rear'd his sceptre to the sky.
>
> ...
>
> Then *Jove* from *Ida*'s top his horrors spreads;/ The clouds burst dreadul o'er the *Grecian* heads;/ Thick light'nings flash: the mutt'ring **thunder rolls**;/ Their strength he withers, and unmans their souls.

And from John Dart, "[Westmonasterium. Or The History and Antiquities of the Abbey](https://books.google.com/books?id=tlcjUSzyWGsC&pg=PA270&dq=%22His+Thunder+roll%27d,+his+ruddy+Light%27ning+drove%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7_qyz2rXPAhUC5mMKHTuvARIQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=%22His%20Thunder%20roll%27d%2C%20his%20ruddy%20Light%27ning%20drove%22&f=false)" (1723), reproduced in Charles Spurgeon, *The Poetry of Westminster Abbey* (2008):

> Then shook the Earth, impatient of her * Load,/ And Storms on high bespake an angry God:/ His **Thunder roll'd**, his ruddy Light'ning drove,/ Threw down the impious Pile, and scorch'd the Grove.